# How to update product position (number) in specific category programmatically

Tags: category, position

I would like to set all position-numbers in one specific category to 100 instead of 0 (default). Id like to do this once - not for future products in that category.

Thx in forward!

Comment: Thanks for your reply and I am not to good in setting that up. Do you make a .php file from your answer and set that in the root directory?

Comment: Correct. I set up a file and run it once. But be aware of http://fishpig.co.uk/magento/tutorials/run-magento-code-externally/ to be able to run the code from the answer.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try this:

```
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage::getModel('core/store')->load(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID));
$categoryId = 22; //replace with your category id
$newPosition = 100; //replace with your new position
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->setStoreId(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID)->load($categoryId);
$products = $category->getProductsPosition();
foreach ($products as $id=>$value){
    $products[$id] = $newPosition;
}
$category->setPostedProducts($products);
$category->save();
```

Comment: I know I shouldnt, but from time to time I have to tell I LOVE YOU MARIUS :D You are the best of the best of the best!

Comment: Glad to help, but if my wife sees your comment...well... I cannot guarantee your safety :)

Comment: Old question, but is there a reason to set store ID on this operation? I don't see `store_id` in the `catalog/category` table.

Comment: @laketuna. It shouldn't even be a store_id field in the category table. That one is used only for loading the correct attribute values.  Check the eav models for more info.

Comment: Also you can use direct SQL query, for all cats 

`UPDATE catalog_category_product AS ccp SET ccp.position = 10000 WHERE cp.position = 1` 

or for specific category `UPDATE catalog_category_product AS ccp SET ccp.position = 10000 WHERE ccp.position = 1 AND ccp.category_id = 23`

Comment: is there have way to set default position for all products 999 instead of 0 , my question is here https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/241188/magento-add-position-999-when-assign-product-to-category