# Update position product programmatically for one position

Tags: magento-1.7, position

because I can't answer yet to this question: [How to update product position (number) in specific category programmatically](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/11157/how-to-update-product-position-number-in-specific-category-programmatically?noredirect=1#comment76902_11157), because of my reputation. Hereby a new question about the updates for the position of a single category.

How would you only update products in that category with a curtain position, for example position 0. So only products with position 0 will change to the new number and products with  position 10 will keep there position.

Hope someone can help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the same script from the response on the question you referenced and just add a condition.

```
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage::getModel('core/store')->load(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID));
$categoryId = 22; //replace with your category id
$newPosition = 100; //replace with your new position
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->setStoreId(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID)->load($categoryId);
$products = $category->getProductsPosition();
foreach ($products as $id=>$value){
    if ($value == 2) {//change position only if `$value` 2
        $products[$id] = $newPosition;
    }
}
$category->setPostedProducts($products);
$category->save();
```

Comment: thanks for your reply and just tried a couple of things, but did not work yet. How would it look like if you would want to change only products with position 2? Thanks!

Comment: I edited the answer. you just need to modify the condition in the if statement. It's basic programming.

Comment: Thanks so much, you are great and works purfactly. I only placed 1 = sing instead of ==